# How to filter json data while Fetching in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs3

Hi I want to filter datas when fetching. For example: in to do list I want to filter only finished datas. Here is part of my fetch code:

Json db: http://localhost:3000/yapilacaklar.

```
<script>
 mounted(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/yapilacaklar')
      .then ((res)=>res.json())
      .then ((data)=>this.yapilacaklar=data)
       // I want to add filter parameters here
      .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
  }
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the computed for this:

```
computed: {
    // a computed getter
    yapilaFinished () {
      // `this` points to the component instance
      return this.yapilacaklar.filter((data)=> data.finished === true)
    }
}
```

or just when you get the data filter the data:

```
mounted(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/yapilacaklar')
      .then ((res)=>res.json())
      .then ((data)=>this.yapilacaklar=data.filter((d)=> d.finished === true))
       // I want to add filter parameters here
      .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
  }
```

Comment: I think in computed one ( first all of datas coming from database than filter...)
and for second one filtering work 1 time before fetching so it can be faster.. what you  think?

Comment: It will depend: With the `computed` you will still have all the data cuz yapilaFinished it with other property so in that property you only will have the finished data and in the property yapilacaklar all data. if you need only the finished data I recommend filtering that in the service otherwise if you want to play with the data in the front-end filtering the data with computed will be better than doing polling for every change.